# DynamoDB: Retrieve item with partition key

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

DynamoDB in my service has partition key that can have duplicate entries.
My understanding is `load` function in dynamodb mapper requires both hashkey and rangekey.

If I want to retrieve just by hash key, is below code the best solution?

```
DynamoDBQueryExpression<Domain> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Domain>()
                .withHashKeyValues(domain);
        return dynamoDBMapper.query(Domain.class, queryExpression);
```

Comment: Do you have a composite primary key (i.e. composed of the partition key and the sort key)?

Comment: Yes, I have a composite key i.e, combination of partition key and sort key is unique

Answer (score 0):

If your table has only a partition key defined then you should be able to get the single item with only the PK

```
Domain item = mapper.load(Domain.class, id)
```

If you have both keys defined you should use a "begins with" query

```
DynamoDBQueryExpression<Domain> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Domain>()
    .withKeyConditionExpression("pk = :v1 and begins_with(sk, :v2)")
    .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);
```

More examples [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Methods.html#DynamoDBMapper.Methods.load)